# Reference for Fundamental Group of infinite product

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, infinite-product, functors

Suppose $(X,x)$ and $(Y,y)$ are two pointed compact manifolds. Every introduction to algebraic topology mentions the result

$$\pi(X \times Y, (x,y)) \cong \pi(X, x)  \times \pi( Y, y) $$

where $\pi(X, x)$ say denotes the fundamental group with basepoint $x \in X$ et cetera.

It seems, for compact manifolds at least, a modification of the finite proof along with Tychonoff's theorem should spit out the infinite version of the above

$$\pi \left (\prod_i X_i, (x_i) \right ) \cong\prod_i \pi(X_i, x_i).$$

I would like to cite this result as part of a counterexample, ideally introducing as little machinery as possible. So far I can only find the result as an exercise. Does anyone know a good reference for the complete proof?

Comment: Related https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1594608/counterexamples-on-homotopy-equivalence-and-infinite-product

Comment: There is no need for "compactness" or Tychonoff or whatever, this is true under no hypotheses on the $X_i$ whatsoever except of course that they are spaces. The proof is easy : a loop in the product is just a product of loops (take each coordinate) and a pointed homotopy in the product is just a product of pointed homotopies (take each coordinate)

Comment: I agree the proof is straightforward. The problem is I would like to employ a little bit of algebraic topology as part of an example that otherwise has very little algebraic topology (and for an audience that doesn't know much of it). So I would like to just cite some reasonable-sounding facts rather than trying to prove things from scratch.

Comment: Ideally I would like to avoid even defining the fundamental group, and instead just say "it is a gizmo with these properties: . . ."

Comment: The fundamental group is calculated by looking at maps out of the circle into your space modulo maps out out of the cylinder into your space. To check that the homotopy groups of a product are the same as the product of the homotopy groups you use the fact that maps into products decompose as a product of the maps onto the individual spaces meaning that both the maps from the circle decompose correctly and the maps from the cylinder decompose directly.

Comment: The “idea” is that products work well with maps and the fundamental group is maps modulo maps.

Comment: @Daron low level properties like "product preserving functor" hardly ever follow from some other high level theorems. And even if they do you will most likely encounter a circular reference.

Comment: Would you know a good reference where they prove this low-level property? It's easy to find proof of the finite product result in textbooks. But those same textbooks usually leave the infinite version as an exercise.

Comment: I can hardly see a proof of the finite case that isn't a proof of the infinite case : there is no distinction between the proofs. Again, this all boils down to the property that : a map $X\to \prod_i X_i$ is entirely determined by its projections $X\to X_i$, and every famiy of projection defines such a map. That's all there is to it (no finite/infinite distinction), and if a proof does something differently, I would be very surprised. I suggest you write it down and see for yourself : if this does not work, then tell us where you have trouble

Comment: I agree with you. The trouble is I want to say "by [$1$] lemma $2.23$ the fundamental group of $\prod _i X_i$ is $\prod_i \pi(X_i)$". Can you suggest what [$1$] should be?

Comment: @Daron I don't know any book that has this. But you can quote Stackexchange. What's wrong with that?

Comment: That might work. Except I cannot find a complete proof on Stackexchange either. I think I will just find a proof for binary products that immediately generalizes and then say the proof for infinite products is analogous. I have gotten away with that before!

Comment: @Daron isn't the answer linked by Javi good enough? Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a proof of this (for arbitrary homotopy groups, not just $\pi_1$) as Proposition 4.2 in [Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html), if you just want a source you can cite.  The proof is only two sentences long and gives very little detail, though, so this is not a good reference if you want a detailed proof to refer readers to.